# 入れ子になった連想配列から、それぞれの要素の数を数えたい

Tags: php, laravel, array

以下の画像のような、入れ子になっている連想配列から「文字列A」と「文字列B」が何回出現したか、それぞれ数えたいです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

`array_count_values` で取得することを試みましたが、`array_count_values` は要素をキーにして集計するので、入れ子になっている配列から取得しようとすると以下のようなエラーが出てしまいます。

```
array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER values!
```

このような、入れ子になっている配列から、「文字列A」と「文字列B」が何回出現したかカウントするには、どのようなコードを書くべきでしょうか？
以下のサイトを参考に試行錯誤しましたがやはり不明なままなので、教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

https://stackoverrun.com/ja/q/3887188

(追記)
以下のようなコードを書いております。

```php
    $row_count = 1;

    foreach ($file as $row)
    {
        // 1行目のヘッダーは取り込まない
        if ($row_count > 1)
        {
            //各値を取得する
            $id =      mb_convert_encoding($row[0],"UTF-8", array("ASCII","JIS","UTF-8","EUC-JP","SJIS"));
            $answer1 = mb_convert_encoding($row[7],"UTF-8", array("ASCII","JIS","UTF-8","EUC-JP","SJIS"));

            $out_arr[] = array($answer1);

        }
        $row_count++;

    }
    echo count($out_arr);

    print_r( array_count_values( $out_arr ) );
}
```

Comment: 連想配列の情報は、可能であれば画像ではなく文字として質問に貼り付けてみてください。 / また、参照されているサイトは StackOverflow のコンテンツをコピーしているサイトです。日本語で読めるという利点はあるかもしれませんが、なるべくなら直接 [StackOverflow の投稿](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14375369) を参照することをおすすめします。

Comment: 内側の連想配列はキー・バリューペアを１つずつしか持たないようですから、連想配列からバリューを簡単に取り出せるでしょう。
それらを配列に入れていく際に、「文字列A」と「文字列B」との一致を数えるようにすると見通しの良いプログラムになると思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まずはエラーをきちんと理解しましょう。

> array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER values!

とあるのでarray_count_valueに渡しているデータの中身（`$out_arr`）を見てみてください。おそらくStringとint以外の型が入っていると思います。

おそらく中身が

```
array(
 0 => array(0 => "文字列A"),
 1 => array(0 => "文字列B"),
 2 => array(0 => "文字列A")
)
```

的な配列になっていると予想しますが、array_count_valueに渡すべき配列は以下のようにするべきでしょう

```
array(
 0 => "文字列A",
 1 => "文字列B",
 2 => "文字列A"
)
```

となると何が起きているかというと
単純に$out_arrの作り方が間違っていることになります。

具体的に言うと以下の部分

```
$out_arr[] = array($answer1);
```

配列に追加する`[]`を利用して末尾に追加していますが何を追加しているかというと$ansertを配列にしたものを追加してしまっています。

つまりは余分な配列を追加して、配列の次元が深くなってしまっています。

```
$out_arr[] = $answer1;
```

とするべきです。

まずはエラーを理解する、エラーからきちんとデバック（echoでもxdebugでもいいので）してみて正しいデータかどうか確認する。間違ったデータを作っているところを見直すを繰り返してみてください。

Comment: こちらでできました、誠にありがとうございます。デバッグの方法についても、勉強します。